# How do I add “index, follow” to all search results pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

Currently search results pages have the following meta robots:

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex, follow' />
```

I’d like to instead have :

```
<meta name=’robots’ content=’index, follow’ />
```

Is there a way to do this with Yoast?

i used this function :

```
add_filter('wpseo_robots', 'yoast_no_home_noindex', 999);
function yoast_no_home_noindex($string= "") {
    if (is_search()) {
        $string= "index,follow";
    }
    return $string;
}
```

but the result is this :

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex, follow, index,follow' />
```

Comment: Why is there `noindex` on your pages? You should try to understand why you have this before trying to change it.

Comment: By default, Yoast seo plugin does not allow indexing of search results. A change must be made in the codes of this plugin. The Yoast plugin believes that this is against Google's guidelines.

Comment: Yoast SEO makes sure your internal search pages are set to ‘noindex’ by default. It’s one of Yoast SEO’s hidden features. This is not an editable setting, because it’s simply how it should be done according to the Google Guidelines, and we fully agree with them on this.

Comment: If you fully agree with Yoast on noindexing SERPs, then why do you want to change it? Additionally, you mention it's not an editable setting, which indicates you've researched and determined it can't be changed: what do you expect to gain from asking this question?

Comment: it is editable with youst source code . but i can not find that !

Comment: One reason to noindex search pages is to stop hackers from getting dubious pages indexed on your website. If search pages are indexed they could get any search query indexed on your site and try and get you to rank for dubious things.